# Vaadin Button doesn't disable on click after removing and readding it

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

Many of my views rely on removing and adding components depending on what the user can see, but, when doing this the components end up broken. For example buttons that disbleOnClick(true) stop working.

A simple example to reproduce:

```
Button buttonWithDisableOnClick = new Button("Button with disable on click");
buttonWithDisableOnClick.setDisableOnClick(true);
buttonWithDisableOnClick.addClickListener(event -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        event.getSource().setEnabled(true);
    }
});

add(
    new Button("Remove button from view", event -> remove(buttonWithDisableOnClick)),
    new Button("Add button to view", event -> add(buttonWithDisableOnClick)),
    buttonWithDisableOnClick
);
```

After removing and adding the button you will notice that it no longers disables after a click.

Is this the intended result ? Is there a way of removing and adding a component and stopping this from happening ?

Comment: There is ticket reported about similar problem in Vaadin's issue tracker, but Vaadin's devs have not been able to verify it, could you copy you question there. https://github.com/vaadin/flow-components/issues/1401

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed now in Vaadin 20.0.8 and newer, and the fix has been backported to 14.6 and 14.7 as well.